# Blurry SVG on Safari After CSS transform scaling

Tags: css, svg, safari, transform

I have an SVG logo that I am using on a site. I have applied some CSS transforms to the SVG for scaling and translating. It works Chrome and Firefox perfectly, but Safari both desktop and iOS render a blurry image after the second transform. ([Codepen link](http://codepen.io/micahmills/pen/zGbvyM))

```js
$('.click').click(function() {
  $('.svg').toggleClass('animated');
});
```

```css
.svg {
  display: block;
  width: 10em;
  height: 10em;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  background: url("http://blessing.micahmills.net/wp-content/themes/BlessingTourism/library/images/svg/BlessingLogo.svg") no-repeat top center;
  background-size: contain;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transform: scale(3) translate(0, 50%);
      -ms-transform: scale(3) translate(0, 50%);
          transform: scale(3) translate(0, 50%);
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .5s;
          transition: transform .5s;
  /*animation: scale .75s linear 2.5s forwards;*/
  -webkit-animation: logoFadeIn .75s linear .5s forwards;
          animation: logoFadeIn .75s linear .5s forwards;
}
.svg.animated {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1) translate(0, -1.75em);
      -ms-transform: scale(1) translate(0, -1.75em);
          transform: scale(1) translate(0, -1.75em);
}

@-webkit-keyframes logoFadeIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes logoFadeIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="click">Click Me Twice</button>
<a href="#" class='svg'></a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this is apparently a bug with Safari. I found a way to work around it by changing the scale to a scale3d. The catch is that the largest that the scale3d can be is (1,1,1). So basically you have to scale down from the larger size.

The code is now

```js
$('.click').click(function() {
  $('.svg').toggleClass('animated');
});
```

```css
.svg {
  display: block;
  width: 10em;
  height: 10em;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  background: url("http://blessing.micahmills.net/wp-content/themes/BlessingTourism/library/images/svg/BlessingLogo.svg") no-repeat top center;
  background-size: contain;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-33%, 33%) scale3d(1, 1, 1);
      -ms-transform: translate(-33%, 33%) scale3d(1, 1, 1);
          transform: translate(-33%, 33%) scale3d(1, 1, 1);
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .5s;
          transition: transform .5s;
  /*animation: scale .75s linear 2.5s forwards;*/
  -webkit-animation: logoFadeIn .75s linear .5s forwards;
          animation: logoFadeIn .75s linear .5s forwards;
}
.svg.animated {
  -webkit-transform: translate(-33%, -33%) scale3d(0.3, 0.3, 0.3);
      -ms-transform: translate(-33%, -33%) scale3d(0.3, 0.3, 0.3);
          transform: translate(-33%, -33%) scale3d(0.3, 0.3, 0.3);
}

@-webkit-keyframes logoFadeIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes logoFadeIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="click">Click Me Twice</button>
<a href="#" class='svg'></a>
```

Comment: Doing this makes the SVG super pixelated in Firefox then.

Comment: This didn't resolve the problem in Safari for me, my scaled up SVG is still blurry.

Comment: I can use higher numbers than 1 for `scale3d`, but the results are still blurry. So might be that the solution just works because you scale down and is unrelated to `scale3d`. But it's the browsers fault not yours. Btw. using `zoom` created perfectly sharp results but is not standard and harder to transition because of the missing transform origin.